# Ruby `bundle install` not working on OpenShift

Tags: ruby, openshift, bundler

I'm working on a Ruby script, it's not a web or Rails app. It's working well locally with Capybara and PhantomJS but I don't know how to run it after pushing to a Ruby 2.0 app in Openshift.

I ssh to app-root/repo and tried `bundle install --without development`, but it outputs:

```
Gem::InstallError: mime-types requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing mime-types (2.99), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mime-types -v '2.99'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Gemfile is:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "capybara"
gem "poltergeist"
gem "mailgun"

group :development do
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "chromedriver-helper"
  gem "launchy"
end
```

Gemfile.lock was generated locally and pushed. Local Ruby is RVM 2.0, on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

It's most likely something simple but I've never used Openshift. Does anyone have any ideas?

- `ruby -v` is `ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]`.
- `which ruby` is `/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/bin/ruby`.
- `which bundler` is `/usr/bin/bundler`.

Comment: Are you install ruby on openshift?  Looks like it's using an old version, hence the error...

Comment: @ I'm supposed to have a Ruby 2.0 app on Openshift. Bundler path seems to be the vendor dir in app-root, but the ruby command is in /opt/rh, so I'm getting confused. Perhaps bundler is an older version...?

Comment: It says ruby is an old version, ssh into the machine and run `which ruby` and then `ruby -v`

Comment: @Anthony `ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]`. `which ruby` is `/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/bin/ruby` and `which bundler` is `/usr/bin/bundler`.

Comment: Oh, well... I downgraded my app to 1.9.3 and bundler is working now.